# Slider {Loop} images not showing

Tags: php, html, css, slider

I have encountered a problem with a slider I am using.

Here is my project website : http://websitedemonuz.com/mista2/index.html

The problem is, when I loop the sliders everything works fine but images doesnot show on the browser.

I checked out and I can see the images on the console. Any idea what might be the problem?

Here is My CODE

```
    <div class="tp-banner-container main-banner">
        <div class="tp-banner white-slide " >
        <ul>
            {loop="slide"}
            <li data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="7" data-masterspeed="500" data-thumb=""  data-saveperformance="on"  data-title="Intro Slide">   

            <!-- MAIN IMAGE -->
            <img src="{$value.image}" alt="" data-bgposition="center top" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat">
            <!-- LAYERS -->





        <div class="tp-caption grey_heavy_72 fade start"
            data-x="60"
            data-y="610" 
            data-speed="1000"
            data-start="1000"

            data-splitin="none"
            data-splitout="none"
            data-elementdelay="0.1"
            data-endelementdelay="0.1"
            style="z-index:7; max-width: auto; font-size:20px; letter-spacing:2px; max-height: auto; white-space: nowrap;">MİSTA PROJE
        </div>


        <div class="tp-caption black_heavy_60 fade start"
            data-x="60"
            data-y="640" 
            data-speed="1000"
            data-start="1000"
            data-easing="Power3.easeInOut"
            data-splitin="none"
            data-splitout="none"
            data-elementdelay="0.1"
            data-endelementdelay="0.1"
            style="z-index: 7; max-width: auto; max-height: auto; white-space: nowrap; text-transform:uppercase; line-height:72px;">{$value.description}
        </div>


        <div class="tp-caption customin rs-parallaxlevel-0"
            data-x="left"
            data-y="bottom" 
            data-customin="x:0;y:0;z:0;rotationX:0;rotationY:0;rotationZ:0;scaleX:0;scaleY:0;skewX:0;skewY:0;opacity:0;transformPerspective:600;transformOrigin:50% 50%;"
            data-speed="0"
            data-start="10"
            data-easing="Power3.easeInOut"
            data-elementdelay="0.1"
            data-endelementdelay="0.1"
            style="z-index: 6;"><img style="width:100%;" alt="" src="tpl/images/slides/yellow-bg.png">
        </div>



        <!-- LAYER NR. 11 -->
        <div class="tp-caption customin tp-resizeme rs-parallaxlevel-0 fade"
            data-x="60"
            data-y="820" 
            data-customin="x:0;y:0;z:0;rotationX:0;rotationY:0;rotationZ:0;scaleX:0;scaleY:0;skewX:0;skewY:0;opacity:0;transformPerspective:600;transformOrigin:50% 50%;"
            data-speed="1000"
            data-start="1000"
            data-easing="Power3.easeInOut"
            data-splitin="none"
            data-splitout="none"
            data-elementdelay="0.1"
            data-endelementdelay="0.1"
            data-linktoslide="next"
            style="z-index: 12; max-width: auto; max-height: auto; white-space: nowrap;"><a href='tpl/work-detail.html' class='largeredbtn'>PROJEYİ GÖR</a>
        </div>


    </li>{/loop}    
</ul>
<div class="tp-bannertimer"></div>  </div>
</div>  
<div class="divider-dark"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you checked out and can see the images on the console, the issue is coming from css or js.

Comment: There is no problem with css or js, have you checked the project website?